# How to use flutter with own compile of dart-sdk

Tags: flutter, dart

*Background*

The Dart-SDK HTTPClient seems to be incompatible with the API I want to write a flutter app against. Its a stupid simple "bug", and I created a pull request for it [here](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/pull/53451).
Now, until this mighht become part of an official release, I want to use m own compiled version of dart sdk.

*What I did*

So I tried following https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/wiki/Building, which worked.
I even got a `dart` binary, with which I can compile a test dart program and verify that the bug is resolved for me.
Than I tried copying `out/ReleaseX64/dart-sdk/` from the build over `flutter/bin/cache/dart-sdk`.
After some googling I also copied `dart-sdk/bin/snapshots/frontend_server.dart.snapshot` to `flutter/bin/cache/artifacts/engine/linux-x64/frontend_server.dart.snapshot`.

But still, trying to run my app I get:

```
Wrong full snapshot version, expected '8b4ce61baff624ad78be1b732fe65e44' found '7dbbeeb8ef7b91338640dca3927636de'
```

*My questions*
Basically I am wondering what I have to do to use that verison of dart-sdk with flutter.

- Do I have to compile the dart-sdk for all targets (e.E. android) or is it fine if I only compiled it for linux?
- Why am I getting the snapshot error? What else do I have to copy or do?